# How to start elevated ConEmu default task from command line?

Tags: conemu

For the purpose of defining shortcut keys in an AutoHotkey script, I want a command line that will start the default task elevated.  I have a matching task that starts elevated, however, since the script will be shared between computers, which may have different default tasks, I don't want to specify the task name.

Something like `-single -new_console:a` is not allowed because `-cmd` or `-run` is required before `-new_console`.

The only solution I've come up with is to clone the desired admin task to a generic name on each computer, like so `-single -run {default-admin}`.  Obviously not ideal if I ever want to change the settings for the task that was cloned.

Comment: Do you know the name of the task you want to start?

Comment: Yes, but as I said, I don't want to specify the task name.